# Adding HTML elements that are not part of TinyMCE content

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce

I wonder if there's a way with TinyMCE to add HTML elements, but without these elements being part of the content (i.e. if I call `getContent()` they will not appear).

My use case is to add for example a small toolbar to edit an element, and this toolbar should not appear in the code returned by `getContent()`. I couldn't find anything about it in the doc. Any idea if TinyMCE allows something like this?

Comment: Wouldn't you write a plugin that sits in the toolbar of the editor itself?

Comment: For toolbar, I guess so, but it's more a general question. It's also how to provide alternate rendering for certain elements. For example a link to an audio file could be displayed as an audio player, but you wouldn't want the audio player to saved with the document. Not sure if I'm approaching this problem right actually.

Comment: I have an application where I need to be able to manipulate the content of Tiny in a variety of ways. I convert the html to JSON, which is easier to work with. Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure which HTML elements will remain using the `valid_elements`, `invalid_elements` and `extended_valid_elements` options.

The `valid_elements` option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.

Example usage:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  valid_elements : 'a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br'
});
```

The `invalid_elements` option instructs the editor to remove specific elements when TinyMCE executes a cleanup.

Example usage:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  invalid_elements : 'strong,em'
});
```

The `extended_valid_elements` option is very similar to `valid_elements`. The only difference between this option and `valid_elements` is that this one gets added to the existing rule set.

Example usage:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  extended_valid_elements : 'img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]'
});
```

Check out the Tiny documentation for more information:

- [valid_elements](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements)
- [invalid_elements](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#invalid_elements)
- [extended_valid_elements](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements)